# Import CSV Utf-8

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin

I'm using this python script for import all the data to my application form a CSV file.

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
#CSV ubication
csv_filename="route"
#django
ruta_django="route"
ruta_project = "route"

import sys,os
sys.path.append(ruta_django)
sys.path.append(ruta_project)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from gestion.models import Cliente, Oficina, Departamento

import csv
lectorCSV = csv.reader(open(csv_filename), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')

for fila in lectorCSV:
        if fila[0] != 'cliente':
                departamento = Departamento()
                c = Cliente.objects.filter(nombre=fila[0])
                o = Oficina.objects.filter(nombre=fila[1],cliente_id=c[0].pk)
                departamento.cliente_id = c[0].pk
                departamento.oficina_id = o[0].pk
                departamento.nombre_departamento = fila[2]
                try:
                        departamento.save()
                except:
                        pass
```

In the CSV file there are words like "administración" and when it saves in the database it appears like: "Administraci?n"

i tried with     # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*- but the problem persist.

Comment: Are your csv file saved as "utf-8" encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csv` module outputs `str` objects, whild Django uses and expects `unicode` strings. You need to convert the strings from the CSV document to unicode strings.

If your CSV contains UTF-8 encoded strings, use `.decode('utf-8')`:

```
c = Cliente.objects.filter(nombre=fila[0].decode('utf-8'))
o = Oficina.objects.filter(nombre=fila[1].decode('utf-8'), ...
```

You can replace 'utf-8' with another encoding, of course. More details on unicode and str can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

The `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` header is used to determine the encoding of strings *in the source code of the current file*, if they contain special characters. Since all strings in the code are simple ASCII, it is not required here.